# Is there an easy way to detect shake motions on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, gesture

I need to detect a shake movement on a Windows Phone 8 device, in order to launch a specific action. How can I do that ?

I found several mentions of a "ShakeGesture.dll" library made by Microsoft for WinPhone7, but the only place where it was available (AppHub) was replaced by the Dev Center website...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's odd. Looks like the AppHub to DevCenter rename broke the download links.

I've uploaded the library to my domain in the meanwhile until those links get fixed @ http://JustinAngel.net/Storage/ShakeGestures.zip

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example on how to use the Shake Gesture Library:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/04/01/shake-gestures-library-a-windows-phone-recipe.aspx

You should be able to add a reference to the ShakeGestures.dll assembly to get started. If you're using the Windows Phone 8 SDK, I believe this library is included - you'll just need to add the reference.

**UPDATE:**

You should be able to download it with this link:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219094

I found that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Sensors). If you scroll down to "Locations and Sensors" about 2/3 of the way down, there's a link to download the gesture library as well as an example.

**UPDATE 2:**

Hmm. It appears that download link *was* the sample project. The ShakeGestures.dll doesn't seem to be in it either. I don't have VS2012 on my computer here at work, but if you do, you could open up the sample solution and see if it is referencing that DLL somehow, and maybe see where it points? It seems like it *has* to be using it...I just can't open it in VS2010.

Comment: As I said, I know this library, I'm just totally unable to find it for download anywhere on the web :D All the links are broken...

Comment: Right, but I thought it should be included (i.e. you shouldn't need to download it). Are you using the WP8 or WP7 SDK? I'm not familiar with WP7, but from the article it sounds like you should just be able to add the reference without downloading anything.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate. Unfortunately, the library is not shipped with any of the WinPhone8 SDK dlls :/ I can't understand why Microsoft changed their website url without a proper redirection to the available resources...

Comment: Yes that is really odd, definitely a mistake on their part. Thankfully, @JustinAngel was nice enough to upload the DLL(s) for you. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Download ShakeGestureLibraryCS from Windows Phone Developer Samples: 
   http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Shake-Gesture-Library-04c82d5f
2. Download C# project and Build (for Release) to create the 'ShakeGestures.dll'
3. Add Reference to your WindowsPhone project.

Comment: NB: Alternatively if you download a pre-built dll you will have to unblock it first before you can add it as a Reference to your project. Right-click the dll file to open 'Properties' window and click 'Unblock'.