# Windows Phone: how to manage shake events?

Tags: event-handling, windows-phone, accelerometer, win-universal-app, shake

The accelerometer is activated (if I set ReadingChanged it works).
Why the shaking event isn't handled?

```
namespace AppExample
{
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
    private Accelerometer accel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        accel = Accelerometer.GetDefault();
        //accel.ReadingChanged += accel_ReadingChanged;
        accel.Shaken += accel_Shaken;
    }

    void accel_Shaken(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerShakenEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("shaken");
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mind, there is  helper librairy called ShakeGestures to handle shake gestures for windows phone 8. check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505482/is-there-an-easy-way-to-detect-shake-motions-on-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows Phone 8 , Shaken event won't trigger and does not raise any errors according to [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer.shaken?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Otherwise it seems like a weird bug to me , I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: the device says Windows Phone 8.1 Update

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Dispatcher in order to show the result on the main thread.

```
namespace AppExample
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        Accelerometer accel;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            accel = Accelerometer.GetDefault();
            accel.ReadingChanged += accel_ReadingChanged;
            accel.Shaken += accel_Shaken;
        }

        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            LabelTest.Text = "Shaken!! " +  args.Reading.AccelerationX.ToString();
        });

        async private void accel_Shaken(object sender, AccelerometerShakenEventArgs e)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                _shakeCount++;
                ScenarioOutputText.Text = _shakeCount.ToString();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you put the "await" part? however I think you intend to use the readingChanged event but I wanted the Shaken one, provided by the framework

Comment: if I'd want to make an UI update I'd use dispatcher but I was using Debug class to send a message to Visual Studio

Comment: the problem is that the handler is never called